# Drawing logic circuits using circuit_macros

Tags: diagrams, circuits, engineering

I am trying to draw a circuit logic diagrams using `circuit_macros` and it is not straightforward for me. I just read the manual of `circuit_macros` and then some of the publicly available examples at CTAN.

Here is the circuit I wish to draw:
 [image: capture]

So far, here is what I have accomplished. But I don't know how to draw the vertical lines with the NOT gates.

[image: diagram]

```
.PS
#scale=2.54
log_init

[
right_

jog = AND_ht/2*L_unit
lgt = L_unit*5

  X1: AND_gate
    line left 8*lgt from X1.In1
    line left 5.5*lgt from X1.In2
  X2: AND_gate at X1+svec_(0,-AND_ht*3/2)
    line left 5.5*lgt from X2.In1
    line left 4*lgt from X2.In2
  X3: AND_gate(3) at X2+svec_(0,-AND_ht*3/2)
    line left 9*lgt from X3.In1
    line left 6.5*lgt from X3.In2
    line left 3*lgt from X3.In3
  X4: OR_gate(3) at X2+svec_(AND_ht*3.5,0)
    line right jog from X4.Out; "\textsc{output}" ljust
    line left from X4.In2 to X2.Out
    line left jog*3 from X4.In1 then up X1.Out.y-X4.In1.y then right to X1.Out
    line left jog*3 from X4.In3 then down X4.In3.y-X3.Out.y then right to X3.Out


]
.PE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first solution;

```
% `logic.cir'
.PS

scale=25.4
log_init

#setrgb(0,0,1) # Blue Color
#dot(,,1)

O:(0,0)

"A" at Here above;line down_ elen_/2;dot;{A:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LA:line down_ to (Here.x,A.end.y);

"B" at (elen_,0) above;line down_ elen_/2;dot;{B:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LB:line to (Here.x,B.end.y);

"C" at (2*elen_,0) above;line down_ elen_/2;dot;{C:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LC:line to (Here.x,C.end.y);

right_

X1:AND_gate(2) at (3*elen_,LC.y+15)
line from X1.In1 to (LA.x,X1.In1.y);dot
line from X1.In2 to (LB.x,X1.In2.y);dot

X2:AND_gate(2) at (X1.x,X1.y-15);
line from X2.In1 to (LB.x,X2.In1.y);dot
line from X2.In2 to (C.x,X2.In2.y);dot

X3:AND_gate(3) at (X1.x,X1.y-30);
line from X3.In1 to (A.x,X3.In1.y);dot
line from X3.In2 to (B.x,X3.In2.y);dot
line from X3.In3 to (LC.x,X3.In3.y);dot

line right_ elen_ from X2.Out;X4:OR_gate(3) with .In2 at Here;
line right_ elen_/2 from X1.Out;corner;line down_ to (Here.x,X4.In1.y);corner;line to X4.In1
line right_ elen_/2 from X3.Out;corner;line up_ to (Here.x,X4.In3.y);corner;line to X4.In3

line right_ elen_/2 from X4.Out; "X" ljust

.PE
```

And output

[image]